# How do I POST/GET to the root of a route?

Tags: node.js, express

In my very simple app I have a users route which is hit when I browse to http://localhost/api/users

Is it possible for me to handle a post or get request to that url without appending anything extra to the route? Using the code below the route handler fires when I post to http://localhost/api/users/new but not to http://localhost/api/users and when I try get http://localhost/api/users/13 but not http://localhost/api/users

I know I could use router.post('/', function(req, res) {}); to post to http://localhost/api/users/ but that extra slash seems inelegant

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var users = require('./routes/user');
var app = express();
app.use('/api/users', users);
module.exports = app;
```

routes\user.js

```
var express = require('express');
var User = require('../models/user');

var router = express.Router();

router.post(function(req, res) {
    // post to root
});

router.post('/new', function(req, res) {
    // post to /new
});

router.get(function (req, res, next) {
    // get root
});

router.get('/:id', function (req, res, next) {
    // get /id
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in routes/user.js, you can simply write:

```
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
        // post to /api/user or /api/user/
});    

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
        // get /api/user or /api/user/
});
```

This would work for both: `http://localhost/api/users` as well as `http://localhost/api/users/`

Also, there's nothing inelegant about having a `/` at the end of the url!

Comment: I was just meaning that being forced to have a `/` at the end of my url wouldn't be ideal. Turns out that it's not being forced at all. Thanks haywire

Answer (score 1):

You can use an empty route like this :

```
router.get("", function (req, res, next) {
    // get root
});
```

You will be able to access to `/api/user` as well as `/api/user/`

Answer (score 0):

Also you can handle the route with the `route` method of `router` to simplify the code and make it more "elegant" :

```
router.route('/')
.get(function(req, res){}) // GET method of /api/users
.post(function(req, res){}) // POST method of /api/users
.put(function(req, res){}) // PUT method of /api/users
.delete(function(req, res){}) // DELETE method of /api/users
```

http://expressjs.com/es/api.html#router.route